# Resetting ui.Select in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

Below I have shared the link.
The issue - ui.Select remebers previous selections - even after being reset.
Consequentially, if the user picks the same value twice - onChange is not activated.
I am working in code editor with JavaScript

https://code.earthengine.google.com/4341dde5f526ef48f2eae20be42eb2b0

Answer (score 1):

`ui.Select` does not change its value when a placeholder text is changed. Therefore, within `Reset` button while resetting the items (according to me unnecessary) and changing the placeholder text to "Choose a location2..." of the `select` button, you are not changing the value of select, but merely changing the text that is displayed on the `select` button. This is why a change is not registered when you click on the same location again. You can verify this by printing `select.getValue()` after you click on Reset.

I think you want to set the location value to default (0,0) when you click on reset. Then, if you again click on the original location, a change will be registered. To achieve that, you can change your reset function as follows:

```
var Reset=ui.Button({
  label: "Reset Dropdown",
  onClick: function () {
    select.setValue("Choose a location...")
    // select.items().reset();
    // select.items().reset(Object.keys(places));
    // select.setPlaceholder('Choose a location2...');
    }
    
});
```

And explicitly set the default location within the `select` button.

[Link](https://code.earthengine.google.com/f1e36826e2fd3ad4d80f67bdc37ad9df) to complete code.

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer by Noel Gorelick from developers forum, just add a line to onclick function,         `select.setValue(null, false) //JUST ADD THIS LINE` :

```
//Try the following sequence:
//Select MTV (will print Registerd a change); then click reset dropdown (select will reset to placeholder); then select MTV again
//And nothing will happen; whereas if u select PEK or ZRH, it will print (registered a change)


var places = {
  MTV: [-122.0849, 37.3887],
  PEK: [116.4056, 39.9097],
  ZRH: [8.536, 47.376]
};

var select = ui.Select({
  items: Object.keys(places),
  placeholder: 'Choose a location...',
  onChange: function(key) {
   Map.setCenter(places[key][0], places[key][1]);
   print('Registered a change');
  }
});

print(select);

var Reset=ui.Button({
 label: "Reset Dropdown",
 onClick: function () {
    select.setValue(null, false) //JUST ADD THIS LINE
 }
});

print(Reset);
```